# Convert event in Magento2?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2, php-7

For the event name

> cataloginventory_stock_revert_products_sale event

in Magento 1, what is the equivalent event in magento2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not a core event [as pointed out by Raul](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/217281/3535).

This event is a part of the extension **[r-martins/magento-stock-history](https://github.com/r-martins/magento-stock-history)**. You can see a rewrite to the class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock` and injecting the event the rewrite class as you see below:

File: [`app/code/community/JR/StockHistory/Model/CatalogInventory/Stock.php`](https://github.com/r-martins/magento-stock-history/blob/master/app/code/community/JR/StockHistory/Model/CatalogInventory/Stock.php)

```
<?php

class JR_StockHistory_Model_CatalogInventory_Stock extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock
{
    public function revertProductsSale($items)
    {
        parent::revertProductsSale($items);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('cataloginventory_stock_revert_products_sale', array('items' => $items));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So there wont be any core event corresponding to this. Either you need to use an M2 extension corresponding to this module or use your own development to accomplish the same.

Comment: @PriyaM please accept any of the answer if it helped. please dont leave a question as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that event **cataloginventory_stock_revert_products_sale** is not available in a default Magento1 installation